# Merging python dictionaries based on value comparing

Tags: python

I have two `dictionaries` :

```
dict1 = {'key1': [val, val, val], 'key2': [val, val, val]}
dict2 = {'key1': [val, val, val], 'key2': [val, val, val]}
```

I need to find in `dict1` and `dict2` keys with the same values and create a new `dict` with that keys (`dicr3 = {'key1': key1}`). Is there better way to do this instead of double `for` loop?

```
for key, val in first_dict.items():
    for key2, val2 in sec_dict.items():
        if val == val2:
            print(str(key) + " : " + str(key2))
```

Comment: you need to merge on values equal or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your values to tuples. This way, they become hashable and you can put them into a dict:

```
dict1 = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'key3': [2,3,4], 'key4': [1,2,3]}

same_lists = {}

for d in [dict1, dict2]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        same_lists.setdefault(tuple(v), []).append(k)

print(same_lists)
# {(1, 2, 3): ['key1', 'key4'], (3, 4, 5): ['key2'], (2, 3, 4): ['key3']}
```

Now you only need to iterate over the values of your dict and look for multiple keys:

```
for common_keys in same_lists.values():
    if len(common_keys) > 1:
        print(common_keys)
# ['key1', 'key4']
```

This solution is `O(n)`, compared to your `O(n**2)` code.

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

```
{key1: key2 for key1, value1 in dict1.items() for key2, value2 in dict2.items() if value1 == value2}
```

Comment: It's still double `for` loop, but quite clean. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's just a simplified form of your solution but it'll run faster than former one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there better way to do this instead of double for loop?

Yes, you could use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function instead.

```
dict1 = {'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [4, 5, 6]}
dict2 = {'key1': [4, 5, 6], 'key2': [7, 8, 9]}
for k1, k2 in zip(dict1, dict2):
  pass
```

It's unclear what merge operation you are trying to achieve, therefore I will let you handle your own case but set are a good way to perform merge operations.